# Rails passing variable to jBuilder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, openlayers, jbuilder

Fixed and solutions incorporated into the OP. A combination of comments by @max here and to my related posting [Rails connecting to jBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60610788/rails-connecting-to-jbuilder). Edits are with `// Was:`

I'm trying to get values through a `has_many :through` relationship. Three main databases: people, locations (which has street address and other information), and the join table, `years` which links the person to a particular address on a specific date.

```
# models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :years, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :locations, through: :years

# models/location.rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :years
  has_many :people, through: :years

# models/year.rb
class Year < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :person
```

`years` links the person to a particular address on a specific date.

As I understand it the flow is that the `show.html.erb` calls `javascript/packs/olPersonMap.js` which then calls `show_locations.json.jbuilder`. How do I pass the `person.id` to jbuilder?

From `views/people/show.html.erb` (class is probably not needed now, refactoring needed).

```
// Was: <div id="map" class="map"></div>
 <div id="map" class="map" data-url="<%= person_locations_path(@person) %>"></div>  
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'olPersonMap' %>
<div>
```

From `javascript/packs/olPersonMap.js`.

```
// Near the top of the file
var urlJSON = $('#map').data('url') + '.json'
// and much further down in the code
new VectorImageLayer({
  title: 'Where lived and worked',
  imageRatio: 2,
  source: new VectorSource({
    // Was: url: '../people/show_locations',
    url: urlJSON
    format: new GeoJSON()
}),
```

From @max 
jBuilder was in `app/views/people/show_locations.json.jbuilder`, now `app/views/people/locations/index.json.jbuilder`. Leaving code out as it wasn't the main problem (although it did have few errors).

And this

```
# app/controllers/people/locations_controller.rb
module People
  class LocationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_person

    def index
      respond_to do |f|
        f.json
      end
    end

    private
    def set_person
      @person = Person.eager_load(:locations)
                      .find(params[:person_id])
      @locations = @person.locations
    end
  end
end
```

and `routes.rb`

```
resources :people do
  resources :locations, only: [:index], module: :people
end
```

In summary, how do I pass person.id to the jBuilder? Or am I going at this all wrong?

Thank you @max. I need to work on understanding what the controller is doing. Lots of moving parts. `https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/people/124` is the Leaflet version. Will push this OpenLayers version after some refactoring to remove all the trial stuff.

Comment: To jbuilder or to view and JS?

Comment: @mechinicov. I missed your response. But I think it's to jBuilder. The error is:      Started GET "/people/show_locations" for ::1 at 2020-01-03 10:34:14 -0800
      Processing by PeopleController#show as */*
        Parameters: {"id"=>"show_locations"}
        Person Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
        ↳ app/controllers/people_controller.rb:108:in `set_person'
      ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Person with 'id'=show_locations:
        app/controllers/people_controller.rb:108:in `set_person'

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass `id` or complete URL of action (which I would prefer) using HTML `data` attribute.

> show.html.erb

```
<div id="person-details" data-url="<%= @person.id %>"></div>
```

> javascript/packs/olPeopleMap.js

```
new VectorImageLayer({
  title: 'Where lived and worked',
  imageRatio: 2,
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: `../people/show_locations/${$('#person-details').data('id')}`,
    format: new GeoJSON()
}),
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that isn't doing it. From the console:

    new VectorImageLayer({ 
    
      title: 'Where lived and worked',
      imageRatio: 2,
      
      source: new VectorSource({
      
     url: '../people/show_locations/${$('#person-details').data('id')}',
     
                                         ^
     format: new GeoJSON()
     
    }),
    
    console.log(url)----    
    The caret is pointing at the # in '#person-details'

Comment: you are using a `single quote` which is wrong. For javascript string interpolation use `backquote` as in the answer

Comment: or simply use string concatenation  `'../people/show_locations/' + $('#person-details').data('id')`

Comment: ` Rendered people/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 10684.1ms | Allocations: 24597)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do` Not sure where the single quote came from. But the above is the current response.

Comment: were you able to find some solution?

Comment: Thanks for asking. but no. I've tried both your and @max suggestions. I updated the OP. I get a little lost in Rails much less in working with JavaScript. Not sure I was clear in my previous response to you, but I now have the backquote. The json is not being produced. But no errors.

Comment: ` url: '../people/show_locations/' + $('#person-details').data('url')` seems to be the correct syntax to pass the id, but still doesn't trigger building the geojson.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60610788/rails-connecting-to-jbuilder where I'm using to Leaflet which I have working and go on from there. I hope back to OpenLayers eventually

Answer (score 0):

First setup a nested route that delivers the JSON you want to consume:

```
resources :people do
  resources :locations, only: :index, module: :people 
end
```

---

```
module People
  class LocationsController
    # GET /people/1/locations.json
    def index
      @person = Person.includes(:locations).find(params[:person_id])
      @locations = @person.locations
    end
  end
end
```

Rename your view `app/views/people/locations/index.json.jbuilder`.

Then setup the map container in the view:

```
<div id="map" class="map" data-url="<%= person_locations_path(@person) %>">

</div>
```

If your doing it the right way there is no reason to go near the `.js.erb` nonsense that just makes a mess of everything since it makes your server get involved in the state of the client.

Don't try to put different script tags on different pages. Its not a good approach - especially if turbolinks is involved. Instead create handlers that augment different elements on the page if the are present (in this case the #map element) that go in your "static" `/javascripts/packs` directory.

This keeps the seperation of concerns in place - the server just delivers data that the client consumes and it lets your javascript be concatenated, minified, cached and delivered via a CDN instead of having Rails serve up interpolated `.js.erb` soup.

It also avoids turning your Rails app into a bunch of RPC style routes that just update the client.

In OpenLayers you should be able to get the element that the map is bound to through the target property of the map.

```
new VectorImageLayer({
  title: 'Where lived and worked',
  imageRatio: 2,
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: map.target.dataset.url,
    format: new GeoJSON()
}),
```

Comment: Error `olPersonMap.js:271 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined` on the line `url: map.target.dataset.url`. Where does the syntax for `map.target.dataset.url` come from? PS  `olPeopleMap.js` is renamed to `olPersonMap.js` as that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is incorporated into the OP. Thank you @max.

PS. I changed `olPeopleMap.js` to `olPersonMap.js` as it was more logical.

Answer (score -3):

Rails runs on Server, JavaSciprt is scripting language runs on browser(client). Basically, there is no way to pass data from Rails to Javascript directly. So you need to third store to pass data between Rails and Javascript like HTML data attribute, HTML hidden filed,...