# Rails connecting to jBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaflet, jbuilder

Chrome error:

```
jquery.js:8678 GET http://localhost:3000/people/locations/location_data.geojson 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:8678
ajax @ jquery.js:8327
jQuery.<computed> @ jquery.js:8464
getJSON @ jquery.js:8448
makeMapTwo @ mapPersonLeaflet.js:22
(anonymous) @ mapPersonLeaflet.js:10
```

I'm trying to get values through a `has_many :through` relationship. Three main databases: people, locations (which has street address and other information), and the join table, `years` which links the person to a particular address on a specific date.

```
# models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :years, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :locations, through: :years

# models/location.rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :years
  has_many :people, through: :years

# models/year.rb
class Year < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :person
```

`years` links the person to a particular address on a specific date.

From `views/people/show.html.erb` (of course the page for a particular person which I hope to show details about the person including locations they were associated with).

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>  
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'mapPersonLeaflet' %>
<div>
```

From `javascript/packs/mapPersonLeaflet.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  makeMapTwo(); // LINE 10 in Chrome error above
});
function makeMapTwo(){
  var mapVar = L.map("map", { center: [34.040951, -118.258579], zoom: 13 });
  L.tileLayer('https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/bkm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mapVar);
  $.getJSON("locations/location_data.geojson", function (data_data) { // LINE 22 in Chrome error above
```

I put the jBuilder file in a folder `views/people/locations/` because if I put it in `/people` I got an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Person with 'id'=location_data:
  app/controllers/people_controller.rb:118:in `set_person'
```

`views/people/locations/location_data.json.jbuilder`

```
json.type "FeatureCollection"
json.features @person.years do |year|
# Person has_many :locations, through: :years  
  json.type "Feature"    
  json.properties do
    json.set! "marker-color", "#C978F3" # will make this different for resto and resid a
     # json.title year.resto
    json.name year.full_name
  end
  json.geometry do
     json.type "Point"
     json.coordinates [year.location['longitude'], year.location['latitude']]
  end # json.geometry
end # features
```

Never gets to the above file. Fails at `$.getJSON("locations/location_data.geojson", function (data_data) {` with the error in Terminal

```
Started GET "/people/locations/location_data.geojson" for ::1 at 2020-03-09 18:47:05 -0700

NameError - uninitialized constant People:
```

I can't figure out which `People` it's referring to. I know it's not getting to the .jbuilder doc because if I delete everything in that doc I get the same error.

Something wrong with my paths. Typo somewhere?

From `routes.rb` I have this line `get 'people/locations/location_data', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }`

PS. I tried this a couple of months ago as an OpenLayers script, but came back to Leaflet since I have had success with Leaflet and hope to go back to the OpenLayers where I was having related problems [Rails passing variable to jBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548291/rails-passing-variable-to-jbuilder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by just creating a nested route that serves up the JSON to populate the map:

```
resources :people do
  # ...
  resources :locations, only: [:index], module: :people
end
```

Then setup a controller:

```
module People
  class LocationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_person
    # GET /people/1/locations.json
    def index
      respond_to do |f|
        f.json
      end
    end

    private
    def set_person
      @person = Person.eager_load(:locations)
                      .find(params[:person_id])
      @locations = @person.locations
    end
  end
end
```

You can rename the template `/people/locations/index.json.jbuilder`.

Then setup the map element so that it has a data attribute that tells the javascript where to load the JSON from:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "",
        class: "map personal-map",
        data: { src: person_locations_path(@person, format: :json) }
%>
```

Also get rid of `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'mapPersonLeaflet' %>` - *just say no to inline script tags*!

You can then just create a script in your assets pipeline that looks for elements with the `personal-map` class and augments them:

```
function personalMap(el){
  var map = L.map(el, { center: [34.040951, -118.258579], zoom: 13 });
  L.tileLayer('https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/bkm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
    .addTo(map);
  $.getJSON(el.dataset.src).done(function(data){
    L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map)
  });
  return map;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // you could also use $('.personal-map').each or the less sucky ES6
  // equivilent
  var personalMaps = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName('personal-map'), 
    personalMap
  );
});
```

If you want to pass any other information from the view to the map (like the bounds or zoom) use data attributes on the map element.

Comment: I purposely choose not the use a geoJSON content type. It works anyways with JSON and requires less fiddling.

Comment: Thank you for advancing my knowledge. The content_tag is not parsing correctly. I get on the page `{:class=>"map personal-map", :data=>{:src=>"/people/108/locations.json"}}` and of course the geojson doesn't get built nor does the map show. `rails routes` => `                     person_locations GET    /people/:person_id/locations(.:format)                                                   people/locations#index`  https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag didn't offer me any clues to

Comment: Yeah I should have realized that it needs a second argument with the content (or a block). That's why its treating the options as content. Edited. Also the official rails docs are at [http://api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org). apidock is just an annoying site with way to much google juice.

Comment: `<div class="map personal-map" data-src="/people/108/locations.json"></div>` but `locations.json` not being built. No errors in Chrome nor in terminal. I put the module in a concern, but `include LocationsController` then results in an error `wrong argument type Class (expected Module)` which suggests this isn't the right way to bring in the module. The error is the `include` as emptying the concern file results in the same error.

Comment: What does "not being built" actually mean? Is the ajax request being sent (check the network tab in chrome)? What is the response?

Comment: And no - this should not be moved into a concern. Every module is not a concern - concerns are just a rails convention for mixins. This module serves as a namespace. It lets you seperate between `People::LocationsController` that serves locations belonging to a person from `::LocationsController` that serves all the locations. Whatever your doing there just stop it. If you want to see a simple demo app https://github.com/maxcal/tracker

Comment: No XHR. All shows ` Document: 108 Script: application-e515c36a86502148fa7a.js Other: favicon-3aad3ea5975bdc843280ae2dadd5f84e1b4dfe9cbadbd10ada02cc52d9c3f585.ico ` Copied and edited slightly for clarity. Also nothing in Terminal to suggest a geojson is being built. On another Leaflet containing page I get `Processing by MapController#line_data as
  Rendering map/line_data.json.jbuilder` and an XHR. I'm working on your next comment which may explain why it isn't working. I put the model in both models and controllers to no effect. I'll look at the demo app carefully. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The demo needs some better seed data for the markers to actually be in bounds but it loads the json data just fine. The assocations are also not quite right but good enough for the purpose.

Comment: comments were almost all needed. I had other problems, one getting the jBuilder doc right and secondly issues with Leaflet and Rails Webpacker (SO had the solution/workaround). The one suggestions that didn't work was removing `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'mapPersonLeaflet' %>` Thinking it might be a routes issue, I ran `rails routes` and got this result `person_locations GET    /people/:person_id/locations(.:format)                                                   people/locations#index`. Thank you @max. I still hope to understand all of this.

Comment: If you get rid of the inline script tag you still need to actually require your javascript file in `application.js` my point was just to move it so that its compiled together with your application pack - so that the script tag is in the layour and not in the view being rendered and thus won't be evaluated over and over if you're using turbolinks.

Answer (score 0):

Your route does not specify the controller and action it maps to, add the `:to` parameter to fix that:

```
get 'people/locations/location_data', :to => 'people#location_data', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

I assume the router interprets the route differently otherwise.